# How to add more criteria to this IF(COUNTIF formula?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

I have a formula that I want to add more criteria to but not sure how to write it out:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($O$4:$O$36,O4)>16,1,2)
```

I want to add further criteria that continues on from if O4 counts >16 times in this list, then P4 will be `1`:
if O4 counts <=15 times, then P4 will be `2`;
if O4 counts <=10 times, then P4 will be `3`;
if O4 counts <=5 times, then P4 will be `4`;
else P4 will be `5`.

The formula above only goes up to "if O4 counts >16 times in this list, then P4 will be 1, else it will be 2"

How do I finish this formula?

Here is an EXAMPLE:

[image]

Comment: have you tried countifs?  With a screenshot of your layout, I might be able to get you a formula.

Comment: No I have not. How would that work?

Comment: It lets you use multiple criteria in a count, but if you want multiple outcomes based on conditions, having some nested IF statements might be the idea.  I think that when you get to that point there might be something else you can use.  Like lookup tables.

Comment: I thought this was simply a matter of finising off the formula I had given...I guess not.

Comment: It might be.  I'm not sure though based on what you've posted.  The information isn't in my head like yours.  Just not familiar enough with what you are trying to do.  Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Ok I will, working on an example to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With COUNTIF:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,a2)>15,1,IF(COUNTIF(A:A,a2)>10,2,IF(COUNTIF(A:A,a2)>5,3,IF(COUNTIF(A:A,a2)>=1,4,5))))
```